# Noticable differences to consider when choosing between lambda, method reference and method with Function<> return value

Tags: java

when running this code snippet. Is there any noticeable difference in performance or something else to take into consideration when choosing between a lambda, a method reference or a method with a Function as return value?

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> firstStream = Stream.of("qwerty", "asdfgh", "zxcvbn")
        .map(s -> s.concat(s));

    Stream<String> secondStream = Stream.of("qwerty", "asdfgh", "zxcvbn")
        .map(Main::selfConcatenateReference);

    Stream<String> thirdStream = Stream.of("qwerty", "asdfgh", "zxcvbn")
        .map(selfConcatenateFunction());
  }

  private static Function<String, String> selfConcatenateFunction() {
    return s -> s.concat(s);
  }

  private static String selfConcatenateReference(String s) {
    return s.concat(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance here. Using Streams here already adds some overhead, but I wouldn't micro-optimize here. A more important question is, in my opinion, "what is better readable?"

Comment: And then I would argue that `s -> s.concat(s)` is best understood by future readers.

Comment: For very simple operations like `s -> s.concat(s)` a lambda is fine, but anything slightly more complex IMHO deserves its own method, which can be unit tested, and method reference to it passed to `map()`